# SSIS Unable to Cast COM OBJECT

Tags: visual-studio-2010, com, ssis, sql-server-2012, pervasive

I'm working on an SSIS package just to copy data from remote server to local database. For Data Source, Pervasive connection is used while destination is OLE DB.

However, it pops this error once I open the package from solution explorer:

[image]

I did research and ran `regsvr32 "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\DTS\Binn\dts.dll"` in cmd prompt as administrator. But it does not solve the issue even though the command succeeded.

It may get well sometimes if I restart "SQL Server Data Tools" (visual studio 2010). Still, I'd appreciate it if some one could help find the actual reason and solve it forever.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Please try setting the delay validation to true for both the data flow tasks, save & close the solution and re-open it.

Hope this helps!